# Propositional Logic: 15-symbol (or more) elements of $\mathcal{L_0}$, sentences.

Tags: logic

Let $\mathcal{L_0}$ be the smallest set $L$ of finite sequences of $\textit{logical symbols}= \{(\enspace)\enspace\neg\}$ and $\textit{propositional symbols}=\{A_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying the following properties:

(1) For each propositional symbol $A_n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
\begin{multline}
A_n \in L.
\end{multline}

(2) For each pair of finite sequences $s$ and $t$, if $s$ and $t$ belong to $L$, then
\begin{multline}
(\neg s) \in L
\end{multline} and
\begin{multline}
(s \to t) \in L.
\end{multline}

Give two examples of elements of $\mathcal{L_0}$ with at least 15 symbols each. The
examples should have an interesting structure. For one of these examples,
give a meaningful sentence which has the same structure.

Given the definition above, why can't we just give out nonsense, like
 $s=()()()()()\neg A_1\to \to A_2 A_3 ( )))))$? Is this not in $L$? It is a finite sequence of logical and proposition symbols... why isn't it in $\mathcal{L_0}$? Is it because we cannot define $(\neg s)$? What about the condition (2)?

Here are two such elements of $\mathcal{L_0}$:

Let $A_1, A_2, A_3$ be in $L$.

(a) $s_1 = ((\neg A_1) \to (A_2))\ \to (\neg A_3)$

(b) $s_2 = (A_1 \to A_2) \to ((\neg A_2) \to (\neg A_1))$

Suppose 
\begin{align*}
&A_1 = \mbox{It's cloudy}\\
&A_2 = \mbox{It will rain}\\
&A_3 = \mbox{I'll bring my umbrella}
\end{align*}

Then (b) for example is "If it rains when it's cloudy, then if it's not raining, it's not cloudy."

Do I need an opening and closing parenthesis in addition to what I wrote for any element of $\mathcal{L_0}$? Say, for example, is $A_1 \to A_2$ an appropriate member? Or is $(A_1 \to A_2)$? Are these the same elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(i)* You are right; the "nonsense" : like $s=()()()()()¬A_1→→A_2A_3()))))$ is not in $\mathcal L_0$.

Consider the "inner part" : $¬A_1$ is not correct, because according to (2) of the specification of $\mathcal L_0$ it mus be : $(¬A_1)$.

Also $→A_2A_3$ is not, because according to (2) it must be $(A_2 → A_3)$.

Also the leftmost part : $()$ is not, because we have a couple of parentheses surrounding no symbol.

And so on ...

*(ii)* Regarding your examples (a) and (b), outermost parentheses are missing.

Usually, after the "initial practice" with the formal specifications of $\mathcal L_0$, some useful abbreviations are introduced, like the omission of outermost parentheses; in this case, it is correct to use $A_1 → A_2$ in place of $(A_1 → A_2)$.